# Purging Biztalk DTA Database

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Suddenly , We are receiving an Disk space alerts from  Production BizTalk 2010 database server . Alerts are set if 90% of disk space is full .   I have not noticed any slowness in BizTalk data processing  till now .  Below are points I have noticed :

1. BizTalkDTADb size is ~ 65 GB ( Data file ~ 55 GB + log file ~ 10GB ) . All other database sizes are < 2 GB .
2. SQL Agent Job for purging and archiving DTA DB is not configured .
3. BizTalk is running more than 3 years now.
4. Global Tracking is on from Day 1 .
5. I can see  orchestration Track Events checked in for orchestration tracking and can not find port level tracking checked in .

Below are the action items i have planned till now based on my internet searches :

1. Full Back up of BizTalk databases .
2. Take BizTalk offline
3. Purge BizTalkDTADb  (As we do not have any usage of tracking data) using Terminator Tool .
4. Take BizTalk online again .

I have below questions :

1. I will be doing this for the first time , Could you please validate if I am going towards right direction  .
2. What is the difference between running stored procedure run from SQL agent Job (dtasp_BackupAndPurgeTrackingDatabase) and running terminator tool  to purge DTA DB . Because I read online , that running SP(for full clean up )  might take days to execute because of current size . How much time should terminator tool take ?
3. **I just installed Latest BizTalk terminator Tool v2.5.6.9 available  over internet . But I unable to find "Purge Everything in DTA" option as explained in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amantaras/2014/04/29/purging-trackingdta-db-using-terminator-tool/ .
   What option I should go for clean up of DTA DB ?**

Please let me know if you need more information to answer .

Regards,

Goutamendu

Answer (score 2):

I would rather do the following:

1. Ask to add more disk space immediately to stop alerts and to allow yr prod environment to run smoothly without interruption.
2. Turn off global tracking from BizTalk admin console and restart host instances
3. Configure the purge job and let it cleanup. You can repeatedly configure it to reduce by few days at a time until u come down to where u want
4. You may still need to have DBAs shrink data files to reduce size of file

With this approach your environment will keep running and u be able to reduce DTA db size on the background. terminator tool you should only use if that’s the only resort.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use the Terminator tool.**

It would work, but it's for more extreme circumstances.  Since all you're seeing is a Warning after ~7 years, you can probably take youy time.

Assuming all other Agent Jogs are running without error, including Backup BizTalk Server:

1. Double check with anyone, including Developers, that the Tracking data is not necessary for anything.  If it is not...
2. During a regular downtime, manually backup all the databases by running sp_ForceFullBackup (Mgmt DB), then running the Backup BizTalk Server Job.
3. Run dtasp_PurgeAllCompletedTrackingData (DTA DB).
4. Configure DTA Purge and Archive and enable.

Depending on the size of the tracking database, the purge might take some time.